# iOS Subscription non IAP

Tags: ios, subscription

I'm building an iOS app where the user will get a 30 days trial of the app for free and then have an option to pay to subscribe to the app by paying a monthly fee through our website by API.

Do I still get charged 30% fee from Apple for this?

Comment: That sounds very uncomfortable to users. It is not about 30%, but it is about your app can pass the App Store review process. [Read this](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/)

Comment: For the subscription model, you have to use IAP not your own system.

Comment: We currently use Wild Apricot to manage payments - I guess I am not allowed to use this system then?  My app will still work, it's just after 30 days the user cannot access it.

Comment: [You got to read this](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments)

Comment: You can use an external payment system and subscription, but your app cannot collect payment in the app and it cannot link to the web site that lets the user pay or create an account.  Basically your app would need to present a login screen with no details on how to pay or link to your website.

Comment: thanks for all you comments and feedback!